# How to format given number in Oracle to specific pattern?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a Java Developer but I have a requirement to print given no. in a specific pattern like below in Oracle:

[image]

I tried below approach but it didn't worked for last scenario which I had mentioned in above input/output table 
i.e.

Input: **123456**,

it is giving output like: **P12345**

```
SELECT CONCAT('P', LPAD(my_number, 5, '0')) FROM DUAL;
```

Can you please guide me which function is useful for it ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions201.htm#SQLRF06130

Comment: You should use **TO_CHAR** to display the number in your desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT CONCAT('P', LPAD(my_number, case when length(my_number) < 6 then 5 else length(my_number) end, '0')) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a flexible solution , covering all your examples but also even longer numbers

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  my_number varchar2(255);
  retval varchar2(255);
begin
  my_number := '123456';

  select case when length(my_number) < 6
              then 'P' || LPAD(my_number, 5, '0')
              else 'P' || my_number
         end      
    into retval           
    FROM DUAL;

  dbms_output.put_line(retval);
end;
```

Comment: Why **PL/SQL** when it could be done in pure **SQL**. Moreover, you do not use **DBMS_OUTPUT** in production.

Comment: This is an example you can copy and paste to see its results, only because of that. You can use the select within as you see it fit, this is only logic demo that works as is after being pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Or this.

```
  select concat('P',trim(to_char(1234568,'999909999'))) from dual
       union 
  select concat('P',trim(to_char(1,'999909999'))) from dual
```

Answer (score -1):

It could be done in shortest way by handling the format in which the number is displayed.

You can use **TO_CHAR** to format your output. **fm** format will remove leading spaces.

```
'P'||to_char(column_name, 'fm000000')
```

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT 1 num FROM dual
  3    UNION
  4    SELECT 12 FROM dual
  5    UNION
  6    SELECT 123 FROM dual
  7    UNION
  8    SELECT 1234 FROM dual
  9    UNION
 10    SELECT 12345 FROM dual
 11    UNION
 12    SELECT 123456 FROM dual
 13    )
 14  SELECT num, 'P'||to_char(num, 'fm000000') mynum FROM data;

       NUM MYNUM
---------- --------
         1 P000001
        12 P000012
       123 P000123
      1234 P001234
     12345 P012345
    123456 P123456

6 rows selected.
```

---

**UPDATE**

The above method depends on the fixed number of digits of the number i.e. up to 6. And that is what OP has asked for, a specific pattern. If there are numbers beyond 6 digits, and if the max length of the number is known, all that you need is modify the format to have as many zeroes.

For example, a bank account number or a unique identification number etc. are fixed format.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: This will only work with a fixed maximum length of 6. (not the downvoter though)

Comment: @KevinEsche But that is what OP has posted. He wants a specific pattern. He has not told what should be the pattern above 6 digits. Could you make out any inference? Such requirements are always specific, and doesn't require a dynamic method.  For example, a bank account number is always a fixed length. You know how to handle the display.